# How to change font size in graphics included with \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, fontsize

I woud like to change the font size of the picture inserted by `\includegraphics`.. have used the scaling 1 and the picture occupies my space, but the font in the picture is very small. How can I change the font size on that picture. scaling it more bigger is not the option. Here is the code:

```
\begin {figure} [!htb]
\includegraphics[scale=0.95]{pics/Cascaded_control.pdf}
\caption {Cascaded servo control[Len2]}
\label{cascaded}
\end {figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) You can format code in your post using the `{}`button.

Comment: You can't. It's a picture and `\includegraphics` doesn't touch it. It just dumps it into the document unchanged (possibly scaled).

Comment: While @kahen is most certainly right that you can’t edit a PDF from TeX, you could edit with one of many available PDF editors. I have seen at least the possibility to change the font size. Though, depending on the source this may not even work (right).

Comment: This is one of the main reasons that a lot of folks go out of their way to use `Tikz` and `PSTricks`; it provides consistency in the document. I appreciate it can't be done for every type of picture/image, but when it is possible, it's a good idea :)

Comment: Try to import your PDF picture into [`inkscape`](http://inkscape.org/) and to change the font size...

Answer (score 5):

The `\includegraphics` command is "dumb". All it does is take the datafile handed to it and dump it bit for bit into the resulting document (along with any scaling factor specified).

The upshot of this is that it is not possible to do any processing on `\includegraphics`'ed vector graphics (i.e. PDF and EPS files) such as changing typefaces, font sizes or colours.